# How to collect log and gathering log with elastic & kibana from WEBSITE

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, logging, web, kibana

I am using the Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana collect log a website
Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana How does this ?
The API uses of the website?
Javascript code is?
Or the other way?

Comment: with RESTful API ?

Answer (score 1):

You can log all website content access to [nginx access log](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/)

Parse the nginx access log with logstash and send to elasticsearch. [See more here](https://logz.io/blog/nginx-log-analysis/)

Assuming you can identify resources on your server by URL / context path, you can create separate dashboards in Kibana for APIs/JS/other resources based on path.

Comment: thanks, this guide
 https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-input-http-plugin

help me! with create javascript code and send POST to endpoint to logstash http with automaticaly elastic ...